# Integral of odd function over unit ball

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be an odd function and let $B$ be the unit ball centered in the origin. I wish to prove rigorously that
$$ \int_B f(x) \, dx = 0 \, .$$
Is this correct? And, if it is, how to prove it with rigor?

Comment: Split the integral in $ B=B_+ \cup B_ -$, where these are the upper and lower balls respectively (the last coordinate for example is the relevant one), then do change of variables, use oddity and the symmetry of the ball. I think you can work it now out rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fubini's theorem, your integral can be rewritten as

$$\int \limits _{-1} ^1 \underbrace{ \left( \int \limits _{x_1 ^2 + \dots + x_{n-1} ^2 \le 1 - x_n ^2} f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n) \ \Bbb d x_1 \dots \Bbb d x_{n-1} \right) } _{= g(x_n)} \Bbb d x_n .$$

Notice that

$$g(-x_n) = \int \limits _{x_1 ^2 + \dots + x_{n-1} ^2 \le 1 - (-x_n) ^2} f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, -x_n) \ \Bbb d x_1 \dots \Bbb d x_{n-1} = \\
- \int \limits _{x_1 ^2 + \dots + x_{n-1} ^2 \le 1 - x_n ^2} f(-x_1, \dots, -x_{n-1}, x_n) \ \Bbb d x_1 \dots \Bbb d x_{n-1} = \dots .$$

Perform the change of variables $y_1 = -x_1, \dots, y_{n-1} = -x_{n-1}$. The determinant of the Jacobian matrix of this change of variables will be $(-1)^{n-1}$, so its modulus will be $1$, therefore you won't see it in the integral. The previous line continues then as

$$\dots = - \int \limits _{(-y_1) ^2 + \dots + (-y_{n-1}) ^2 \le 1 - x_n ^2} f(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}, x_n) \ \Bbb d y_1 \dots \Bbb d y_{n-1} = \\
- \int \limits _{y_1 ^2 + \dots + y_{n-1} ^2 \le 1 - x_n ^2} f(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1}, x_n) \ \Bbb d y_1 \dots \Bbb d y_{n-1} = -g(x_n) .$$

This shows that the integral that we started with is the integral of an *odd* function ($g$) on a *symmetric* interval ($[-1,1]$), which is known to be $0$.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use induction? The base case is obvious and then the result follows immediately from Fubini.

Comment: @Chilango: How do you reduce an integral over $B^n$ to an integral over $B^{n-1}$, in order to apply induction? Try it first, and you'll appreciate the simplicity of my answer (which, incidentally, uses the same base case and Fubini's theorem that you mention, too).

Comment: Yes.Now I see it's not as easy as I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Define $Tx = -x.$ Then $T: B \to B,$ hence

$$\int_B f(x)\,dx = \int_B f(Tx)\,|J_T(x)|\,dx = \int_B f(-x)\cdot 1\,dx = -\int_B f(x)\,dx.$$

Therefore $\int_B f(x)\,dx = 0.$

Comment: @BrunoLiegi: In my opinion, this should be the accepted answer, since it is shorter and conceptually simpler than mine (not using induction), and it also doesn't rely upon an unproven base case as my proof does.